# postgres send string to function that takes a numeric

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres function that takes a numeric ie -

```sql
create function format_currency( x numeric ) returns text language sql
    as  $$ select to_char( x, 'FM999,999,999,999,999.00');$$
```

but I have a field which is a text field, and I can't find any way of calling the function on it - the following all give errors:

```sql
format_currency( my_field )
format_currency( my_field::float )
format_currency( my_field::double )
format_currency( my_field::numeric )
```

Comment: What do you expect will be the result of `'gfsuiz&/'::numeric`?

Comment: I happen to know all the values _are_ numeric in this case - but if it was like that, I'd want it to come out as null

Comment: Well, *some* value obviously is no valid number. You can use a PL/pgSQL function catch the `EXCEPTION` and return NULL instead.

Comment: `format_currency( my_field::numeric )` should work. What is the error you get? But the real question is: why are you storing numbers in a  text column? That's a really, really bad idea.

Comment: the data we have comes from another system through another product which imports every field as text - I've no control over that.   If I try my_field::numeric, I just get "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" if the field is blank - because of course this product also puts blanks instead of nulls

Answer (score 1):

If the **only** invalid value is an empty string, you can use:

```
format_currency(nullif(my_field,'')::numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PL/pgSQL function and catch the conversion error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION format_currency(x text) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   RETURN to_char(x::numeric, 'FM999,999,999,999,999.00');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
      RETURN NULL;
END;$$;
```

Comment: but the problem is format_currency never gets called - because the thing dies on converting the field to numeric.      I know I can trivially add an overload of format_currency which takes a text... or even do a case when  expression -  but I thought there'd just be a really easy cast I could do instead, and I was just being silly.

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake. I meant to do the cast in the function. Fixed. `CASE` won't help you here, unless you use a regular expression which catches all non-numeric values reliably. PostgreSQL has no "cast, but return a NULL on error", although it certainly [has been requested before](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/MN2PR15MB2560C23261EFFBFC9F437A5B85D49%40MN2PR15MB2560.namprd15.prod.outlook.com).